# Can two SASS projects share the same node_modules folder and package,json file?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am working on two SCSS projects that share identical dependencies (Bootstrap, Fontawesome, node.js). I would like to maintain the identical dependencies at the root and move the gulpfile.js to project subdirectories.

How can I get the gulpfile.js files in the project one and two subdirectories to use the node_modules in the parent/root directory while keeping the style and watch functions relative to their directory?

Example directory structure

```
|-- bootstrap
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
|-- project_one
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- gulpfile.js
|   |-- sass
|-- project_two
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- gulpfile.js
|   |-- sass
```

Gulfile.js code

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Compile scss int css
function style() {
    return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

// Watch function
function watch() {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.css', style);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem as long as your imports are right, I believe. You could also look into React Workspaces (fairly new) to see if that might solve some of what you're looking for (would type more but am on phone).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that gulp will walk up the directory until it finds the node_modules folder. My issue turned out to be user error, I had miss named a directory which broke the main import in my style.scss file.